# Is it correct to say "he shook milk onto the table"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

A boy was holding a milk carton which has a little milk. He then shook the carton and some milk came out and fell onto the table.

In the dictionary, they say

> [shake](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/shake): [+ object] : to force (something) out of something by shaking
>
> He shook (out) the sand from his sandals.

So, I think I can apply this structure into my sentence "**he shook (out) milk (from his carton) onto the table**" and I omit adverbs in the brackets.

Is it correct to say "**he shook milk onto the table**"?

Comment: I doubt, milk is liquid so clearly you pour it out unless it went sour and why would he do it onto a table? I'd say he pour out the remaining milk or what last drops remained from the carton box into a mug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He shook the carton and **splashed** milk onto the table.

From [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/splash):

> If a liquid splashes or if you splash a liquid, it falls on or hits something or someone:
>
> - Water was splashing from a hole in the roof.
> - Unfortunately some paint splashed onto the rug.
> - She splashed her face with cold water.
> - She poured a large gin and splashed soda into it from a siphon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why no-one suggested "spill", which seems to be the most appropriate choice for the situation.

> From cambridge,
>
> spill (v): to (cause to) flow, move, fall, or spread over the edge or outside the limits of something

See ["Don’t Cry Over Spilled Milk"](http://www.jesustakethepen.com/dont-cry-over-spilled-milk/).

[image]

> "He then shook the carton and some milk came out and fell onto the table."

We would say "He spilled milk on the table."

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It’s acceptable.

But if there’s so little milk in the carton that this can happen, it’s more common to say he *dribbled* the milk onto the table, or he shook *a few drops of* milk onto the table.